# React SetState not updating after axios call when component is unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

It works when I stay on this page. However, when I switch to another tab and come back while the api is processing, setLoading(false) is never triggered.

How can I fix this?

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(!!window.sessionStorage.getItem("isButtonDisabled");
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
   console.log(loading);
}, [loading]);

const showReport = () => {
  setLoading(true);
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("isButtonDisabled", true);
  return axios({
    url: 'api/report/getdata',
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob'
  }).then(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("isButtonDisabled", false);
    setLoading(false);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `.finally()` because `.then()` is triggered only if the promise finishes successfully. More details about finally [in Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally).

To resolve the issue, you might also want to use `useEffect()` [cleanup](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-cleanup-logic-runs-even-though-my-component-didnt-unmount) to call a callback to stop the loading whenever the component gets unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

`ReportLoadingPanel` is showing forever because:

1. `window.sessionStorage.getItem("isButtonDisabled")` always returns a string, so, conversions to `boolean`: `!!'true'` is equals to `true` and `!!'false'` is equals to `true` also. The correct check would look like this: `window.sessionStorage.getItem("isButtonDisabled") === 'true'`
2. Call to the API would be unsuccessful, but you only handle successful cases using `.then()`, to solve this, add a call of `.catch()` after `.then()` and call `setLoading(false)` and `window.sessionStorage.setItem("isButtonDisabled", false)` there too, or, as mentioned above, you can use `.finally()`, as it is being fired regardless `Promise` is resolved or rejected.
3. Delete the first `useEffect` hook and move logic from there to `useState` hook:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(() => window.sessionStorage.getItem("isButtonDisabled") === 'true')
```

Comment: Fixed those and still no luck. setLoading(false) is done in .finally() but still not updated. console.log(loading) is not called and ReportLoadingPanel still shows.

Comment: I just updated my answer, forgot to add the 3rd point, and mention moving `window.sessionStorage.setItem("isButtonDisabled", false)` to `.finally()` too.

Comment: hmm no change.. still not updating setLoading to false